# Fetch data from url if condition is meet

Tags: google-apps-script, conditional-statements, fetch

Is it possible to adjust this code to "get result and save file" only if text at fetched url contains defined text. e.g. "12345" or text "abc is X" where X is number >5
Note: I need to check both expressions ("12345" and "abc is X") and save file if any of them is meet

```
function fetchData() {
    var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl);
    var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName(FILE_NAME);
    return folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

Comment: I've made some progress with this code `if(htmlBody.indexOf("12345")>-1 || htmlBody.indexOf("abc is X")>-1){execute the function}` But how define that X in string "abc is X" must be number >5?

Comment: Try this condition `htmlBody.match(/abc is ([5-9]|\d{2,})/)`

Comment: Tnx @Kos. This do the job. I guess that part \d{2,} means digits 0-9 from 2nd digit? And one more question. How to adjust this formula if original sentence says "abc is (X)". The difference is that X is in () in original sentence and this part of code don't work properly anymore. I've tried this with adding one more bracket but that don't work `htmlBody.match(/abc is (([5-9]|\d{2,}))/)`

Comment: \d{2,} means "two or more digits"

Comment: If you add brackets as "match" characters, you should escape them with "\": `htmlBody.match(/abc is \(([5-9]|\d{2,})\)/)`

Comment: Tnx again @Kos. One more and I'm done I promise. When I look desired webpage it looks like says "abc is 100" in one line but with this code `htmlBody.match(/abc is ([5-9]|\d{2,})/)` I don't get anything back. So I've looked to the sourcecode of webpage and it says:
`<li>
<span>abc is</span>
<strong>100</strong>
</li>`
but between „abc is“ and „100“ apparently isn't space (they are maybe divided somehow) and code doesn't met condition. How to solve that problem?